# lwip FreeRTOS tcp window

Tags: tcp, freertos, lwip

I am using lwip ontop of FreeRTOS to send data to a server. I am trying to maximize the data flow.
I tune several paramerters in "lwipopts.h" but I am always receiving ACK after emitting two packets.
Thanks for helping

NB: simple echo servers (on linux & windows) gived the same result with high advertised TCP_Window size

Comment: Have you configured TCP_SND_BUF? This sets a limit on the amount of buffered send data, including the amount of infight data. So even if the receiver is advertising a large window, LwIP won't send more than TCP_SND_BUF worth of unacked data

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the TCP_NODELAY option in your sending socket?

Comment: Already done, I am using delayed Ack with other optimizations, however, I reached only 50MB/s with fully dedicated bandwidth.

Comment: Ok. For maximizing throughput TCP_NODELAY should not be set I believe. Another thing to check would be that lwIP does not run out of memory in any of the pools (ie memp_malloc() calls). There is debug macros that you can enable to catch that.